# Is it ok for a Handler to quitSafely itself?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, handler

I have a service that creates a background HandlerThread with a Handler using:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("ReportServiceBackgroundThread", Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    thread.start();

    mReportServiceHandler = new ReportServiceHandler(thread.getLooper());
}
```

where ReportServiceHandler extends Handler and overrides `handleMessage(Message msg)` (I personally prefer to work with messages between threads rather than posting Runnables, because it feels safer).

When the service is about to be destroyed, I do:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mReportServiceHandler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(mReportServiceHandler.obtainMessage(REPORT_SERVICE_DESTROY));
}
```

I do not close the thread\handler immediately - I just send it a "top-priority" message, so the handler could cleanup things that were created on its thread (for example, disconnecting a GoogleApiClient).

I catch the REPORT_SERVICE_DESTROY message insides the handleMessage function:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    ...
    switch (msg.what) {
        ...
        case REPORT_SERVICE_DESTROY:
            ... // cleanup code
            ReportServiceHandler.this.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            ReportServiceHandler.this.getLooper().quitSafely();
            break;
    }
}
```

Is it ok to call `quitSafely` from within the thread\handler itself? In most of the examples that I see `quit` is called from outside the handler, which makes sense if you have nothing to clean.

Thanks

--- *Edit* ---
Another solution is to remove the `quitSafely` from `handleMessage` and do:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy");
    mReportServiceHandler.sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue(mReportServiceHandler.obtainMessage(REPORT_SERVICE_DESTROY));
    mReportServiceHandler.getLooper().quitSafely();
}
```

Following the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html#quitSafely()) of `quitSafely`:

> Causes the loop() method to terminate as soon as all remaining messages in the message queue that are already due to be delivered have been handled.

And because we've just added a REPORT_SERVICE_DESTORY message, the actual quit will be done only after the message was handled (i.e. after the cleanup).